# itextsharp stitch 2 pdf pages in one long page

Tags: pdf, merge, itext

I'v found at this forum the code for assembling multipage pdf to a single page

```
var pgSize = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(612, 2984);

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"C:\\Users\\myuser\\Desktop\\PDFTestmerge\\test1.pdf");

Document document = new Document(pgSize, 0, 0, 0, 0);

PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(@"C:\\Users\\myuser\\Desktop\\PDFTestmerge\\testx.pdf", FileMode.Create));

document.Open();

PdfImportedPage page;
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);

table.WidthPercentage = 100;

for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
    page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
    table.AddCell(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(page));
    document.Add(table);
}
document.Close();
```

But i know it's not the right way to do that (skipping the form object) of the pages
 ( what i'v Expressly need )
I use this code with (PdfCopy) to merge pdf ( multipage )

```
Document document = new Document();

PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileStream(@"C:\\Users\\myuser\\Desktop\\PDFTestmerge\\testz.pdf", FileMode.Create));
document.Open();

PdfReader reader;

int n = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < collectFinal.Count; i++)
{
    reader = null;
    reader = new PdfReader(collectFinal[i]);
    n = reader.NumberOfPages;

    for (int page = 0; page < n;)
    {
        copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, ++page));
    }
}
document.Close();
```

How can i combine the (PDFcopy) feature with the code to stitch many page together. I don't really have a code to show because i don't know where to start... i not able to transform pdf(PdfCopy) as image...to place in table
Thanks to help me to understand the approach

Comment: That is a use case not explicitly supported by itext high level APIs yet, but it is possible using its low level APIs.

Comment: Would it be easier, If my primary PDF containing all pages and the task is to delete some pages and finally merge the remaining pages in one big page. ( working with one pdf...and its own content internally )

Comment: What makes it non-trivial, is that you want to combine the contents of multiple pages on a single target page *and* have the annotations from the original pages at the appropriate positions on the target page.

Comment: dont need annotation... But ( Form field ) Maybe it's the same difficulty ?... I know the height of each page...so i know the final height of the big page and the vertical position of each page ( depending which page i'v deleted before )

Comment: Form fields (more exactly: their visualizations) are annotations.

Comment: Thanks for precision